# Is it wise/possible to Extend C: on a Single 1TB Partitioned Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, partitioning

I have a production computer at work that is running 2x 1TB Drives in RAID1
The person who partitioned the drive did so very horribly.

The computer is running Windows XP
C: 40GB
D: 850GB

There is no Unallocated Space anywhere.

Is it possible to somehow shrink the D: and make Unallocated space and attach that to the C:?

It seems like if it is possible the Unallocated space would end up after the D: so I would have to Allocate enough space to move the contents of the D: to the new drive (E:) and then delete the D: and then I would be able to Extend the C: with the unallocated space from the D:?

Then I would have to re-create the D: and move everything back.

Does this sound correct?
Is there a better way to do this or is it even possible?
Is it wise to do?

Even if I cloned the drive to a 2TB drive the Unallocated sectors would still end up at the end and I couldn't extend the C: could I?

Thank you for your time and help on this.

Kind regards.

Comment: What are you doing maling changes to an XP system?  Your plan sounds logically correct, but as you need to back up first, why not just back up, blow away D, expand C and restore. This has less risk and will likely be faster.

Comment: You could also MOVE "big crap" by folder from C: to D: and then junction those folders back to C:.  It does take some finesse to move things without having any open file handles but I do this all of the time to deal with your scenario.  Then identify places you are going to want more space on C: and junction a folder from C: to D: the same way.  It doesn't take long and there is very little risk.  @davidgo suggestion is probably even better.. but I use both methods depending on circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this often on various versions of Windows. Most partitioning tools allow you to *move* a parition. Use the tool of your choice, then follow the steps below:

1. **Backup** your data! Make sure the backup is usable.
2. Verify (chkdsk), then defragment the D: drive.
3. Shrink the D: partition by the amount you want to add to C:. This will leave the released space as unallocated space after D: partition.
4. *Move* the D: partition by the amount just freed. This will "move" the free space before the D: partition.
5. Enlarge C: partition by the desired amount.

No need to create an E: partition.

Comment: Step 1.5: Confirm that the backup actually works.

Comment: Correct, but not so easy. You'd need to restore to another disk, then compare. But this ought to have been done at the time you setup the backup process.